# REGEX lookbehind assertion error in Netezza SQL

Tags: sql, regex, regex-lookarounds, netezza

Good day

I am classifying merchant strings according to their names but I am struggling with merchants that have names which could have multiple pre-cursors. I tried to make use of the negative lookbehind assertion but I am struggling with the following expression:

```
regexp_like(trim(upper(MRCH_NME_POST_ACTION)),'\b(?<!(BIG|XTRA|TOWN|SUPER|U|TOP|SHOP|PICK|MAX|POWER|NU|) )SAVE\s?(SUPERMARKET|HYPER)\b','i')
```

I received the following error code for the regex that I am using in Netezza SQL:

```
ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  0 : Regex: pos(58) lookbehind assertion is not fixed length
Culprit Pattern: \b(?<!(BIG|XTRA|TOWN|SUPER|U|TOP|SHOP|PICK|MAX|POWER|NU|) )SAVE\s?(SUPERMARKET|HYPER)\b
```

Any solutions to the fixed length problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may re-write the pattern so that lookbehinds alterantions are of the same length. As `(?<!(a|bc|def) )` is equal to `(?<!a )(?<!bc )(?<!def )`, you may use

```
\b(?<!(SHOP|XTRA|TOWN|PICK)\s)(?<!(SUPER|POWER)\s)(?<!U\s)(?<!NU\s)(?<!(BIG|TOP|MAX)\s)SAVE\s?(SUPERMARKET|HYPER)\b
```

If we format it you will see that

- `\b` - matches a word boundary
- `(?<!(SUPER|POWER)\s)` - a negative lookbehind with 5 letter words
- `(?<!(SHOP|XTRA|TOWN|PICK)\s)` - a negative lookbehind with 4 letter words
- `(?<!(BIG|TOP|MAX)\s)` - a negative lookbehind with 3 letter words
- `(?<!NU\s)` - a negative lookbehind with 2 letter words
- `(?<!U\s)` - a negative lookbehind with 1 letter words
- `SAVE` - a literal substring
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `(SUPERMARKET|HYPER)` - either of the two values
- `\b` - a word boundary.

**See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HzPxYt/1)**

Comment: Thank you kindly Wiktor. Greatly appreciate your assistance yet again